# PHP сокеты не работают по wss://

Tags: nginx, ssl

Здравствуйте. Перевёл сайт на https и не могу понять, как перевести сокеты.
На http к сокетам шло подключение через `ws://sitename.com:3003`, теперь нужно, чтобы они были доступны по `wss://sitename.com:3003`.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

PHP:

```
$loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:3004');
$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onMessage'));

$webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$webSock->listen(3003, '0.0.0.0');
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
  new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
    new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
      new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
        $pusher
      )
    )
  ),
  $webSock
);

$loop->run();
```

JS:

```
window.phpSocket = new ab.Session('wss://sitename.com:3003',
```

Nginx:

```
server {
    listen   443 ssl;
    keepalive_timeout   70;

    client_max_body_size    500M;
    root /var/www/path/to/site/root;
    index index.php;
    server_name sitename.com;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip            on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied    expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript;


    ssl                     on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_cache       shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout     10m;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему удалось решить самостоятельно!
Подробнее: https://toster.ru/answer?answer_id=1071432#answers_list_answer

Answer (score 0):

перед `server {`

```
upstream websocket {
    server ВАШ_ДОМЕН:3003;
}
```

внутри `server {`

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://ВАШ_ДОМЕН;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
    }
```

Comment: Попробовал, не работает. Просто не идёт подключение.

Comment: не заметил, что вы используете Ratchet. Попробуйте отредактированный конфиг выше.

Comment: Пробовал так - выдавало ошибку "WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 301".

Comment: без дебага на уровне протокола ничего сказать не могу. Может кто другой подскажет. А так совет дебажить с помощью tcpdump к примеру. Посмотреть запустился ли сервер и слушает ли заданный протокол. Может посылать напрямую запросы через curl (или какую-нибудь удобную тулзу), учитывая, что протокол простой (статья на вики хорошо объясняет).